# is this wrong result return with YouTube Data Api v3 or Is this my mistake. This is big problem to me

Tags: api, youtube

I subscribed to this YouTube Channel which has channel id "UCvqhk1yFhKxl_Nz9pCsKuJw"
The total link of that channel is - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvqhk1yFhKxl_Nz9pCsKuJw

Then I checked whether my subscription exists by using google developer page- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

under "check whether a subscription exists"

but for only above channel it returns empty result. for  another channel ids its working properly.

what is this problem.i am android developer and i see this behavior on my android project.i work hard for find this error. but ultimately i see this error for this channel id only.I implemented this error using google developer page for your simplicity.

please help me...

Comment: Check with other channel that has the "Community" tab enabled and has posts/entries on them. If (*with that channel you're testing*) your code works, then, the problem is with that specific channel `UCvqhk1yFhKxl_Nz9pCsKuJw` and you should post a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc). You should post your code here as well in order to check if *maybe* the error is in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am testing this on developer page. Therefore no need codes.